# How to append geographic features into a .dgn file?

Tags: arcobjects, c#, cad

How can I export all the geographic features of a featureclass into .dgn (Microstation) file using C#/ArcObjects? I was able to create a new .dgn file and I want to export all the geographic features of a selected feature class into that newly created .dgn file.